# Edge in IE mode opening Localhost instead of the URL through selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Below is my code in selenium java. Edge is opening in ie mode but it is opening localhost: some random number and is not opening the URL. I was trying to invoke the edge browser through IE driver.**

```
    package com.w2a.rough;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.openqa.selenium.UnexpectedAlertBehaviour;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

    public class ieedgetest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WebDriverManager.iedriver().useLocalVersionsPropertiesFirst().setup();
        InternetExplorerOptions edgeIe11Options=new InternetExplorerOptions();
        Map<String, Object> ops = (Map<String, Object>) edgeIe11Options.getCapability("se:ieOptions");
        ops.put("ie.edgechromium", true);
        ops.put("ie.edgepath", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");     // Edge Browser directory path

        edgeIe11Options.introduceFlakinessByIgnoringSecurityDomains();
        edgeIe11Options.ignoreZoomSettings();
        edgeIe11Options.enablePersistentHovering();
        edgeIe11Options.takeFullPageScreenshot();
        edgeIe11Options.disableNativeEvents();
        edgeIe11Options.requireWindowFocus();
        edgeIe11Options.destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();

        edgeIe11Options.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
        edgeIe11Options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);

        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(edgeIe11Options);
        WebDriver wait = (WebDriver) new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
        driver.get("https://github.com/");
        
    }
    }
```

**POM.XML**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.w2a</groupId>
    <artifactId>PageObjectModelBasics</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
 

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- POI JARS STARTS -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.40.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- POI JARS ENDS -->


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore> false </testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/com/w2a/runner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>


            </plugin>


        </plugins>
        
        <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources/com/w2a/properties</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>log4j.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
        


    </build>


</project>
```